# Minimum Observable Offset Frequency in Leeson's Formula

Tags: frequency, signal-processing, noise, observable-universe

It has been argued in [some publications](https://www.nature.com/articles/2191356a0) that the age of the universe represents a lower limit on observable frequencies (in their paper, corresponding to a value of $10^{-17}$ Hz). The authors do not explain exactly why this is, and my *assumption* is that this is because frequencies lower than $10^{-17}$ Hz would have periods longer than the age of the universe, making it impossible to observe periodic behavior.

My question is whether the above argument holds for the modulation/offset frequencies in [Leeson's](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/1446612) [equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leeson%27s_equation); i.e., offset frequencies with values less than $10^{-17}$ Hz would have periods longer  than the age of the universe, making it impossible to observe the periodic behavior of said offset frequencies.